# How to create time series in batches using cli tool of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know if I can create multiple time series at the same time using Apache IoTDB's Cli tool? If I can do so, how should I write my creating time series command in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write multiple rows as multiple time series using the compiling file tool of Cli in Apache IoTDB, and separate each line with a semicolon, so you can create all the time series you write at the same time.